# Rmarkdown text wrap comments inside code chunks

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trouble getting Rmarkdown to text wrap when it reaches a certain line length. Currently, it adds a horizontal scrollbar, but ideally it would just wrap the text.

I have tried using

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy=TRUE,
tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60))
```

It works on some code chunks but not others.

My first code chunk, it works. (code is on the left, output is on the right)

[image: The comment in this photo properly text wraps]

But later in the document, knitr no longer wraps comments. (code is on the left, output is on the right)

[image: The comment forces a horizontal scrollbar]

How can I force knitr to wrap all the code chunks, including the comments?

Answer (score 1):

That's because an inline comment (after a line of code) can't be wrapped, otherwise the code will be invalid. For example, you can't wrap

```r
1 + 1  # this is a comment
```

as

```r
1 + 1  # this is
a comment
```

If you want comments to be wrapped, you have to write whole lines of comments.

Comment: Then how do I get it to recognize independent lines of comments? https://imgur.com/a/ltCOoig

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by "recognize" or what you want to achieve.

Comment: If I put a comment on its own line, like you suggest, it disappears in the output. The output does not print out the comment in the code chunk when it is on its own line. So:

`1+1 # this is a comment
# broke into two
2+1
# this comment will be ignored`

Comment: The line of comment needs to go before the code. If it is below a line of code, it belongs to the next block of code.